# Tool/Script to Automate File Naming From Metadata

Tags: powershell, macros, metadata, rename, powershell-cmdlet

I have a folder containing 1000+ PDF files with generic names (i.e. *DOC (1)*) that I need to rename with the order number, which is listed inside the file itself. I've had to manually open each document, look for the order number, then change the file name.

I have a spreadsheet list of all of the order numbers contained in that folder. I've used the search function of the file explorer to look up each individual order #, then renaming whichever file comes up. This has reduced the task time substantially but it's still very time-consuming.

Does anyone know of a macro or scrip that I can build to automate the task? Again, I would need something to grab the order number line by line from the spreadsheet, then go to the file explorer to search for any files with that specific term, and finally rename whichever file comes up with said term.

Any and all relevant help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: [ExifTool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) can be used to batch rename files based upon embedded metadata.  If you run `exiftool -s FILE.PDF` on a file and can find the tag name for the order number, you could run a command line `exiftool "-filename<${TAG}_text_text.pdf" DIR` to process all files in the DIR you specify.  You would replace TAG with the name of the tag you found and text with any other text you might want in the name.

Comment: @StarGeek Thank you for the tip. Unfortunately, turns out that the information I need (order numbers) is not stored as metadata when I run OCR tools on the file.